# Information flow using entropy does not give me an output

Tags: probability-or-statistics

Here are few equations to calculate the quantity of information flow (i..e., mutual information):

[image]

I wrote the following `code` (a primitive one) to calculate `x(21)`:

```
ClearAll[dist, prX1aX2, prX2, prX1gX2, H1, H12, x21];

dist = MultinormalDistribution[{Subscript[μ, 1], Subscript[μ, 
    2]}, {{Subscript[σ,1]^2, ρ Subscript[σ, 1] Subscript[σ, 2]}, {ρ Subscript[σ, 1] Subscript[σ, 2], 
     Subscript[σ, 2]^2}}];  

prX1aX2 = 
 PDF[dist, {x1, x2}];  (* joint probability distribution: p(x1,x2) *)

prX2 = PDF[MarginalDistribution[dist, 2], x2];  (* marginal probability distribution of x2: p(x2) *)

prX1gX2 = (prX1aX2/prX2);  (* conditional density of x1 given x2 *)

(* entropy *)
H1 = Expectation[-prX1*Log[prX1], x1 \[Distributed] 
   NormalDistribution[Subscript[μ, 1], Subscript[σ, 1]]]

H12 = Expectation[-prX1gX2*Log[prX1gX2], {x1 \[Distributed] 
    NormalDistribution[Subscript[μ, 1], Subscript[σ, 1]], 
   x2 \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[Subscript[μ, 2], Subscript[σ, 2]]}]

x21 = H1 - H12;
```

This 'code' does not give me any output but keeps running. Where do I do wrong? I need help to find out why it is not working? Also, if possible, make this 'code' more elegant...

Comment: I think there are two main issues.  (1) You're multiplying by the associated density in $H1$ and $H12$ when `Expectation` already includes that.  And (2) `H12` treats `x2` as if it were random:  you've conditioned on a specific value so it's not a random variable.  In fact I think the $dx_2$ in `H12` should be $dx_1$.  A more minor issue is that I'd avoid the use of subscripts until you're ready to make the final result look pretty.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've made a few small changes in the variable names (used "pdf" instead of "pr") and removed the extra use of the probability density functions in `Expectation` as the pdf's are automatically used when the associated distribution is defined.

```
(* Marginal density of x1 *)
pdfx1 = PDF[NormalDistribution[μ1, σ1], x1]

(* Log of pdfx1 *)
logpdfx1 = Log[pdfx1] //. 
  {Log[a_ b_] -> Log[a] + Log[b], Log[Exp[a_]] -> a,  Log[1/a_] -> -Log[a]}
(* -((x1 - μ1)^2/(2 σ1^2)) + 1/2 (-Log[2] - Log[π]) - Log[σ1] *)

(* H1 two ways *)
H1 = Expectation[-logpdfx1, x1 \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[μ1, σ1],
  Assumptions -> σ1 > 0]
(* 1/2 (1+Log[2]+Log[π]+2 Log[σ1]) *)
H1 = Integrate[-logpdfx1 pdfx1, {x1, -∞, ∞}, Assumptions -> σ1 > 0]
(* 1/2 (1+Log[2 π σ1^2]) *)
```

Now construct `H12`:

```
(* Marginal density of x2 *)
pdfx2 = PDF[NormalDistribution[μ2, σ2], x2]
(* Joint density *)
pdfx1x2 = PDF[BinormalDistribution[{μ1, μ2}, {σ1, σ2}, ρ], {x1, x2}]
(* Conditional density *)
pdfx1gx2 = FullSimplify[pdfx1x2/pdfx2]

(* Find log of conditional density *)
logpdfx1gx2 = Log[pdfx1gx2] //. 
  {Log[a_ b_] -> Log[a] + Log[b], Log[Exp[a_]] -> a, Log[1/a_] -> -Log[a]}
(* ((x2 - μ2) ρ σ1 + (-x1 + μ1) σ2)^2/(2 (-1 + ρ^2) σ1^2 σ2^2) + 
   1/2 (-Log[2] - Log[π]) + Log[1/Sqrt[1 - ρ^2]] - Log[σ1] *)

(* H12 two ways *)
H12 = Integrate[-logpdfx1gx2 pdfx1gx2, {x1, -∞, ∞}, 
  Assumptions -> {σ1 > 0, σ2 > 0, -1 < ρ < 1}]
(* 1/2 (1+Log[π]+Log[2-2 ρ^2]+2 Log[σ1]) *)
H12 = Expectation[-logpdfx1gx2, 
  x1 \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[μ1 + ((x2 - μ2) ρ σ1)/σ2, σ1 Sqrt[1 - ρ^2]], 
  Assumptions -> {σ1 > 0, σ2 > 0, -1 < ρ < 1}]
(* 1/2 (1+Log[2]+Log[π]+2 Log[σ1]) *)

x21 = FullSimplify[H1 - H12] /. Log[a_^k_] -> k Log[a]
(* -(1/2) Log[1-ρ^2] *)
```

***Addendum:***

If one is willing to believe that `x1` given `x2` has a normal distribution, then one just needs to find the mean and variance of that distribution to be able to construct `H12`.

```
assumptions = {σ1 > 0, σ2 > 0, -1 < ρ < 1}
(* Direct calculation of mean and variance of conditional distribution *)
meanx1gx2 = Integrate[x1 pdfx1gx2, {x1, -∞, ∞}, Assumptions -> assumptions]
varx1gx2 = FullSimplify[Integrate[x1^2 pdfx1gx2, {x1, -∞, ∞}, 
    Assumptions -> assumptions] - meanx1gx2^2]
(* Alternative method of calculating mean and variance of  conditional distribution *)
distx1gx2 = ProbabilityDistribution[pdfx1gx2, {x1, -∞, ∞}, Assumptions -> assumptions];
meanx1gx2 = Mean[distx1gx2]
(* μ1+((x2-μ2) ρ σ1)/σ2 *)
varx1gx2 = Variance[distx1gx2]
(* -(-1+ρ^2) σ1^2 *)

H12 = Expectation[-logpdfx1gx2, x1 \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[meanx1gx2, varx1gx2^(1/2)], 
  Assumptions -> assumptions]
(* 1/2 (1+Log[2]+Log[π]+Log[1-ρ^2]+2 Log[σ1]) *)
```

Comment: It is well-known about the mean, variance, and distribution of $x_1|x_2$ when $x_1$ and $x_2$ are from a bivariate normal distribution.  I'll add in something that finds the mean and variance using basic *Mathematica* commands but I'll leave out showing that $x_1|x_2$ has a normal distribution.